# Flutter Build Suggestions In Text Form Field

Tags: flutter

I want to have an suggestion field just below the text form field like any search bar.
It is similar but not exactly an search bar. It is in somewhere in my scaffolds body.

I have this stream :

```
Stream<List<String>> getSuggestions(String query) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Products')
        .orderBy(FieldPath.documentId)
        .startAt([query])
        .endAt([query + '\uf8ff'])
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.id).toList());
  }
```

and this builder for it :

```
 Container(
                child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
                  stream: getSuggestions(selectedname.text),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {

                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      print(snapshot.data);
                      return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data![index]),
                            onTap: (){
                              setState(() {
                                selectedname.text = snapshot.data![index];
                              });
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else {
                      return SizedBox.shrink();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

it actually works very well like when I tap it copies text to textformfield. But it looks seperated.
I also tried this :

```
extension SuggestiveTextField on TextFormField {
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context, Stream<List<String>> suggestionStream) {
    final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    controller.clear();
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
          stream: suggestionStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(8)),
                ),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data![index]),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I used it as :

```
              TextFormField().buildSuggestions(context, getSuggestions(selectedname.text))
```

But it breaks my context for example: dislocates other widgets and it can not be seen in context.

So first one is different widget and it is not extension of my textformfield so looks seperated from textformfield . Second one doesnt work .I dont want them to look seperated. What can I do ?